# How to know if an array is "almost" sorted?

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have to decide, given an array of numbers, if either heap sort or merge sort will be faster at sorting it, without actually running them. In order to do that I am trying to find good indicators that might harm performance in both cases such as the length of the array, for example.

I have found that merge sort is exceptionally good at sorting almost sorted arrays. In that sense, I am trying to find a good way to estimate how "almost" sorted an array is but I am not sure how to do that.

I have thought about using the means of the result of subtracting each consecutive element in the array but I am not sure if that is the best approach to this problem. For example:

```
public class AlmostSortedCalculator {

    private static final int[] UNSORTED_ARRAY = {7, 1, 3, 9, 4, 8, 5};
    
    private static final int[] SORTED_ARRAY = {1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9};

    private static final int[] UNSORTED_ARRAY_ = {200, 20, 634, 9957, 1, 890, 555};    

    private static final int[] SORTED_ARRAY_ = {1, 20, 200, 555, 634, 890, 9957};
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AlmostSortedCalculator();
    }

    public AlmostSortedCalculator() {

        calculate(SORTED_ARRAY);
        
        calculate(UNSORTED_ARRAY);

        calculate(SORTED_ARRAY_);        

        calculate(UNSORTED_ARRAY_);
    }

    private void calculate(int[] array) {

        int result = 0;        

        for (int i = array.length - 1; i != 0; i--) {
            if (i != 0) {
                result += array[i] - array[i - 1];
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The result is: " + result / array.length);
    }
}
```

> The result is: 1
>
> The result is: 0
>
> The result is: 1422
>
> The result is: 50

The result of the means seems to be higher when the array is sorted but I am not sure how reliable that indicator is. I am sure there is a better approach for this, but I cannot think of any. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well, the question is, how general the testing method has to be, and what you consider as almost sorted. For example, in `{9, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8};` no element is at it's right place only one is farther than 1 away from it. And do we consider (1,2,3,4) and (4,3,2,1) as sorted? For big, big arrays, you might take 100 random pairs of indexes (random.nextInt (arr.length)) and count, for how many of them index i < j matches arr(i) < arr(j). Above some threshold you define it as pretty sorted and may adjust your threshold. Knowing, whether it shall be asc or desc would be fine.

Comment: Ordinary MergeSort is not good at sorting almost sorted arrays, it treats them as any other, in time O(N Log N). You may want to look at SmoothSort.

Comment: There's are variations of merge sort such as [natural merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Natural_merge_sort) that take advantage of nearly sorted data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd only look at the sign of the subtraction results:

```
/* returns the sign of the expression a - b */
int sign_of_subtraction_result(int a, int b) {
    if ( a < b ) return -1;
    if ( a > b ) return +1;
    return 0;
}
```

You may also call this function `compare()`. 
Note that usual library sorting functions only use this information and require such `compare()`-fuctions.